# Unit-testing on a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, unit-testing

I want to do a unit-testing on a database through overriding or mocking without bringing any changes to the database. Is there any simple way to do it?

```
import sqlite3
from customer import Customer

class DataChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('pos.db')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def customer_has_equipment_attached(self, customerID):
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID == ?;""", (customerID,))
        conn.commit()
        customers = cursor.fetchall()

        if len(customers) == 0:
            print("Customer ID not found in DB")
            return False

        customer = customers[0]
        tmp_customer = Customer(ID=customer[0], Firstname=customer[1], Lastname=customer[2],        

        Age=customer[3], Sex=customer[4], Street=customer[5], Zip=customer[6], City=customer[7],  Nationality=customer[8], IMSIPtr=customer[9], IMEIPtr=customer[10], SubscriptionPtr=customer[11], Email=customer[12], Password=customer[13])

        # Fetch equipment
        if tmp_customer.IMEIPtr != None:
            cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE ID = ?;""", (tmp_customer.IMEIPtr,))
            conn.commit()
            equipment = cursor.fetchone()

            if len(equipment) == 0:
                print('Customer has equipment ID but ID cant be found in DB.')
                return False

        else:
            print('Customer has no equipment attached to profile.')
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a consensus that **unit tests should be isolated from external components** and dependencies, such as the database. In that sense you have two options, either create a Mock for the database calls (which I discourage), or define an interface for abstracting the database from your application and implement a Fake component for use in unit tests. This later approach requires more effort to set up, but in the long term it pays off tenfold, enabling you to write all kinds of unit tests that have a dependency on the database.

A lot of system architecture concepts are involved here dealing with: Software complexity, dependency inversion, test context management, and so forth. If you're interested I have written a language agnostic article that covers these topics in more detail: [On the architecture for unit testing](https://thomasvilhena.com/2020/04/on-the-architecture-for-unit-testing).